# Given a set of intervals and a time t, find one of the intervals containing that time

Tags: algorithm

Intervals have start and end time. 
Intervals can overlap. There might be several intervals containing a time t. It is ok to just return one of them.

This was an interview question. I was able to solve it by sorting the intervals based on end and another time based on start and taking the intersection of the intervals that have a matching start and end. Apparently there are more optimized solutions.

Here is an example: [1, 5] [2, 10] [3, 6] [2, 9] and target is 8. In this case either of [2, 10] and [2, 9] are correct answers.

I guess the point of the question is to precompute a data structures on intervals, so that searches can be run with a complexity of better than linear.

Comment: Why would you sort them: O(nLog n) for the sort alone, rather than iterate until you find one -- worst case O(n)?

Comment: Assuming the numbers corresponding to the intervals start and end were of constant size (could fit in integers), the given implementation could use radix sort and thus have a runtime of O(n), not that I'm saying its a good solution.

Comment: I'm assuming there was a wording mistake in the question: If you simply sorted the list twice and took an intersection as you described, you would get back exactly the same list you started with, maybe in a different order. If you change the word *sorting* for *filtering*, then it actually makes sense as a solution, albeit non-optimal.

Comment: @Richardissimo I am not sure why we get the same array. The array is sorted once by the start, and a copy of that by the end. From each one we find the intervals that meet the criteria (ie for start smaller than the target, for end  greater than the target) and then take the intersection of these two. This still has a bad performance which I know. Just clarifying the wording you mentioned.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Added a bit more info to the question to clarify further. It's because the data can be precomputed, to answer searches that are coming afterward. I had to clarify that. Your point is valid for just one run.

Comment: @apadana Your comment above does not match what the question states: it adds the clause *"from each one we find the intervals that meet the criteria"* - you did not state this in the question. Re-read the algorithm as *you gave it* in the question, and then re-read my comment, it will make more sense. We can only work based on what you tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall11/Lectures/10-augmentedTrees/augtrees.pdf), the question is exactly like an interval tree.

The solution can be found in many resources but I found the pdf mentioned above to be very concise and to the point.

Here is the relevant part to the answer:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the intervals, until you find one where the given time is between the start end of that interval. You can stop at the first one you find. The worst case performance is O(n).

**Edit to add** *because the question has been edited to add the suggestion of pre-computing the answers*

Pre-computing the answers forces the assumption that the times for each interval do not change, and the collection of intervals do not change. This is not stated in the question, but the following is based on that assumption.

If you were to pre-compute the results, you would need to examine the collection for each possible hour. You could do this for *all* 24 hours, or (for a small number of intervals) the list of possible hours is a range from the Minimum of the start hour to the Maximum of the end hour (since all other hours will have no intervals), costing O(n) to calculate both Min and Max. Which approach to choose would depend how many intervals you have. If *n* is sufficiently large then you'd ignore calculating Min and Max, and do it for all 24 hours,

For each possible hour, you would would need to examine the collection for the first interval to match (worst case O(n), for each hour), and store it for future lookup.

They could be stored as an array of references to the intervals, using the hour as the index, yielding worst case O(1) lookup cost.

So if you were doing enough lookups, and assuming that the intervals never change, this would be faster than calculating it each time.

Comment: This was a smart answer!! And I confess it was beautiful! I think maybe the point of the question was that you can pre compute the data, so for any future search the find time can be better than linear, like O(log(n)).